# How to extract left most common characters in a string field in multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some rows that have common groups:

```
Id    Name    Group
1     ABC1    G1
2     ABC2    G1
3     ABC3    G1
4     AXX3    G2
```

At some point I know the group I need to query (**G1** for example). Then I need to query the left most common characters in the `Name` field among the rows filtered by their `Group`. So in this case, I'd get `ABC`.

Can this be performed in one query ? I need to do this in the simplest way possible.

Comment: +1 That is a good one!

Comment: Do you know the exact number of common characters?

Comment: @crudolf, If I knew the exact number of common characters I'd just `substring` them :)

Comment: The question was "how to extract" not "how to find number of" :) sorry & updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by brute force:

```
select groupid,
       (case when min(left(name, 10)) = max(left(name, 10)) then left(name, 10)
             when min(left(name, 9)) = max(left(name, 9)) then left(name, 9)
             when min(left(name, 8)) = max(left(name, 8)) then left(name, 8)
             when min(left(name, 7)) = max(left(name, 7)) then left(name, 7)
             when min(left(name, 6)) = max(left(name, 6)) then left(name, 6)
             when min(left(name, 5)) = max(left(name, 5)) then left(name, 5)
             when min(left(name, 4)) = max(left(name, 4)) then left(name, 4)
             when min(left(name, 3)) = max(left(name, 3)) then left(name, 3)
             when min(left(name, 2)) = max(left(name, 2)) then left(name, 2)
             when min(left(name, 1)) = max(left(name, 1)) then left(name, 1)
        end) as CommonPrefix
from t
group by groupid;
```

If you don't like typing so much, you can also do:

```
select groupid,
       max(case when min(left(name, n.n)) = max(left(name, n.n)) then left(name, n.n) end)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all selet 2 union all select 3 . . .
     ) n
group by groupid;
```

(Or use a `where` clause to get the information for one group.)  For this example, just keep adding integers to the `n` subquery up to the length you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about dirty integer generator:

```
select TT.g, max( MA ) from
  (select t.g, max( left(t.Name,N.n ) ) MA, min( left(t.Name,N.n) ) MI
   from t cross join
    (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
     select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
     select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) N   
   group by t.g, N.n
  ) TT
where TT.MA = TT.MI
group by TT.g
```

Results:

```
+------+-----------+
| g    | max( MA ) |
+------+-----------+
| G1   | ABC       |
| G2   | AXX3      |
+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the maximum substring by counting everything:

```
select k.common, k.setSize, k.number from
(select left(name, z.n) common, count(*) setSize, z.n number 
        from t
        join (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 3 ...) as z
        group by left(name, z.n)) k
order by k.setSize desc, k.number desc
```

which will return you the number of entries having the same common characters in the first x characters. The first line will give you the total number of entries followed by the top subgroup.